# store string with its value into an array: Perl

Tags: perl

I have a Perl file called `grabPet.pl` and a text file called `Pets.txt`

Each pet has a number of toys linked to them. So a: `cat=5`

cat will have 5 toys. They are separated by commas so:

`mouse=3, cat=5, dog=9,`

i want to output these into a formatted table.

I am not looking for the answer just guidance on how I could approach it?

I am thinking possibly a 2d array but I dont think perl supports it.

```
open(FILE, "<pet.txt") || die"could not read);

while (<FILE>) {
      push (@lines, $line);
  }

close FILE;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2Ej6.png

Comment: Your code won't compile. Show actual code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am not looking for the answer just guidance on how I could approach it?

So here are some hints:

1. make sure your input line doesn't end with a newline
   `chomp (my $line = <FILE>);`
2. [`split`](http://p3rl.org/split) your input string:
   `my @parts = split /, */ => $line; # split on commas and whitespace`
3. prepare a **hash** to store your data because it contains key-value-pairs:
   `my %data;`
4. loop over your parts:
   `foreach my $part (@parts) { ... }`
5. in your loop, split the parts in key and value:
   `my ($key, $value) = split /=/ => $part`
6. in your loop, store it in `%data`:
   `$data{$key} = $value;`

**Note**

I leave it to you as an easy exercise to do it with multiple input lines. Also note that you're using `open` wrong here:

```
open(FILE, "<pet.txt" || die "could not read");
```

because the error check won't do what you expect. Replace it by

```
open(FILE, '<pet.txt') || die "could not read";
```

or, better readable:

```
open FILE, '<pet.txt' or die "could not read";
```

and better use lexical file handles, three arguments and include the real error message:

```
open my $file, '<', 'pet.txt' or die "could not read: $!";
...
chomp (my $line = <$file>);
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Parsing

If the data is very orderly, you can `split` on each line. If we split on commata with preceding spaces, we would get the animal-toynum pairs, that we can then split on the equality sign. I would write this:

```
my %toys = map {split /=/, $_, 2} split /,\s*/, $line;
```

Interesting bits are the `map` function and the third argument to split in one case, but not in the other. The reasons for these are documentet in `perldoc -f`, and stem from list-to-hash coercion that takes place here.

You can then take a reference to the hash and stuff it into an array, like `push @array, \%toys`. You can then access the element like `$array[5]{mouse}`, which would give `3` if we just parsed the sixth line.

If the data is more complex, you have to use regexes, e.g

```
my %toys;
while (my $line = <>) {
  while ($line =~ m{ \G \s* ([\w-]+) =\s* (\d+) (?:,|\s*$) }xgc) {
    $toys{$1} += $2;
  }
}
```

This would'nt store each line, but automatically sum the toys for each animal.

#### Data structures

Perl doesn't support multidimensional arrays, but arrays of arrayrefs, which boils down to the same thing.

```
my @AoA = (
   [1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6],
   [7, 8, 9]
);
```

The square brackets denote an anonymous array reference, while curlies would denote an anonymous hash reference. `perldoc perldata`, `perldoc perllol`, `perldoc perlreftut` and friends have more information on these.